# issues with schema.rb file during rails 5 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading to Rails 5, I receive an error message like following every time I try to load from schema (set up a new computer on the app, run `rails db:test:prepare` before running tests, etc.):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 'serial'::regtype::oid
```

Searching around isn't yielding much help. The most relevant thread is this one: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30298 but I am not trying to run any new migrations, nor does the `schema_plus_indexes` gem seem to have anything to do with the issue (the two issues described in that thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, we don't keep migration files around after they have been run against all databases. Because of this, when working on the upgrade to rails 5, there were 0 migration files present. The issue, it seems, is that rails will only automatically "fix" your schema.rb file for you if you are actually running a migration file (even trying `rails db:migrate` with no migration files present won't work).

The solution, for us, was to create a blank migration and run `rails db:migrate` in order to get the schema.rb file properly formatted.